# Scripts dont work on page load in Mvc application which is calling from IOS Webview

Tags: javascript, ios, asp.net-mvc, safari, pageload

In IOS 10.3.2 version, scripts don't run on page load of MVC application which is calling from Webview of IOS application. But when I navigate to another page and turn back, scripts are working properly. Before 10.3.2 there was no problem also. In addition, mvc web application is working well on Safari browser..

Here is my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            // SWIPER SETTINGS-----
            var swiper = new Swiper('#sld_1', {
                pagination: '#pgn_top',
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                paginationClickable: true,
                spaceBetween: 0,
                centeredSlides: true,
                autoplay: 2500,
                autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
                loop: true
            });

            var swiper = new Swiper('.sld_2', {
                slidesPerView: '3',
                paginationClickable: true,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                freeMode: true
            });

        });
    </script>
```

What could be possible reasons for this situation ?

Comment: Do you have jQuery? If so use jQuery document ready

Comment: Yes i tried it also but it didnt work @Krishna

Comment: Maybe the js file related to the swiper is causing the problem. Can you check if the file is loaded ? If not load file using jQuery getscript